# AjaxFileManager File Upload issue syntax error unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I'm using TinyceEditor in my website and I'm using AjaxFileManager to upload images. It works very good in my localhost, but in the remote server while uploading image an error appears and uploading stop.

> Syntax error: unexpected token <

Comment: And people are going to guess what the problem is?

Comment: Ajaxfilemanager  file upload that comes with Tinymce editor is not uploading images in sever. Its working in localhost. is this issue with server or the plugin